# Ускорение работы алгоритма

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Для решения следующей задачи мною был составлен следующий алгоритм.
На вход два аргумента - **data** и **dictionary**. В переменной **data** передается массив объектов вида:

```
  {  
      geometry: [number, number];  
      text: string;  
  }
```

В переменной **dictionary** передается массив строк - слова, которые мы умеем расшифровывать.
*dictionary: string[];*

Чтобы получить секретное сообщение, требуется отсортировать все объекты из массива **data** по первой координате из поля **geometry** по возрастанию, а затем собрать в строку все поля **text** из отсортированного массива.
К сожалению, сообщение закодировано на иностранном языке, а переводчик знает только слова, заданные в переменной **dictionary**. Поэтому если в поле text встречается слово, которого нет в массиве **dictionary**, сообщение невозможно расшифровать.
Программа должна вернуть полученное сообщение или строку "Unreadable message"(в случае, если сообщение содержит слова, которых нет в словаре).
Каким образом его можно улучшить?

```
 module.exports = function (inputData, inputDictionary) {
        const hashMap = {};
            inputData.sort((item1, item2) => item1.geometry[0] - item2.geometry[0]);
            inputDictionary.forEach(elem => {
                hashMap[elem] = true;
                });
            let textMessages = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++){
                if(!hashMap[inputData[i]["text"]]){
                    return "Unreadable message";
             } else {
                textMessages += inputData[i]["text"] + (i === inputData.length - 1 ? "" : " ");
               }
            }
        
            return textMessages;
          }
```

Comment: На сколько часто меняется inputDictionary?

Comment: а где склейка в строку и разбивка на слова-то ?

Answer (score 0):

Что можно сделать, как мне кажется,

1. для того, чтобы понять, что сообщение не переводится не требуется предварительно что-то отсортировывать, ведь потом все равно проверяются все слова `text` из `data` в `dictionary`

поэтому если нерасшифровываемых сообщений больше, чем расшифровываемых, то выгоднее сначала проводить проверку - возможно ли расшифровать вообще или нет - экономим время на сортировке

2. какие именно числа записываются в geometry? если дискретные в небольшом диапазоне (например от 0 до 1000) то сортировку можно провести просто перемещая элементы в такой массив `tmp[1001]`, после чего пройтись по нему и собрать расшифрованную строку
3. зачем вы заполняете hashMap, когда этого не требуется - вы сразу можете идти и собирать расшифрованную строку:

> ```
> module.exports = function (inputData, inputDictionary) 
> {
>     inputData.sort((item1, item2) => item1.geometry[0] - item2.geometry[0]);
>     let textMessages = "";
>     for(let i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++){
>         if(dictionaty[inputData[i].text] === undefined){
>             return "Unreadable message";
>         } else {
>             textMessages += inputData[i]["text"] + (i === inputData.length - 1 ? "" : " ");
>         }
>     }       
>     return textMessages;
> }
> ```

4. кстати эта проверка каждый раз `(i === inputData.length - 1 ? "" : " ");` не нужна - лучше после цикла отрезать последний пробел в строке

Comment: интересно как вы так решили, что конткатенация строк после сортировки происходит через пробел?

Comment: @teran, исключительно по этой строке `textMessages += inputData[i]["text"] + (i === inputData.length - 1 ? "" : " ");`